# How do I remove a summoned Ender Dragon with no AI?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I used the command `/summon EnderDragon ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1}` so that I would have an Ender Dragon that would just sit there.

I then wanted to get rid of it, but doing `/killall EnderDragon` didn't work, neither did `/killallnpc`, and I can't seem to do any damage, even with a diamond sword and maximum strength using commands.

I'm not sure why I can't get rid of it; I think it's because the dragon has no AI, but I need to get rid of it somehow, any ideas?

Comment: Are you on a server with a plugin that adds the killall or killallnpc command? If not, then you can't use those commands. When typing a command in chat, use tab to make sure it is autocompleted.

Answer (score 10):

Use `/kill @e[type=EnderDragon,r=100]` while you are in the same dimension as the Ender Dragon you want to kill. This command doesn't require any command blocks, so you can just type it in the chat.

Comment: `/kill @e[type=EnderDragon]` should work as well, and it would have the added bonus of only needing to be able to see the dragon (or the health bar) without needing to be within 100 blocks of it.

Comment: does not work in 1.14, the type should be ender_dragon

Answer (score 6):

Using mincraft 1.11, `/kill @e[type=ender_dragon]` will kill all enderdragons in your surroundings

Comment: This works for mc 1.12.2, both single player and CraftBukkit version git-Bukkit-9ab758c (MC: 1.12.2) (Impleme
nting API version 1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: In `1.12`, the command isn't working for some reason in Creative Mode with Cheats Enabled.  Tried `/kill @e[type=ender_dragon]` to no avail.  It's still making a ruckus and I can't seem to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

try `/kill @e[type=EnderDragon]` It normally works, unless you are on a server and you are not admin.

Comment: Cheat mode off?

Comment: impossible. also, cheat mode needs to be "on" to summon the dragon, so there's no chance of cheat mode being "off"

Comment: Oh. I was presuming about an already-summoned/there dragon.

Comment: This does not add anything that the other answer hasn't already stated. Duplicate answers are frowned upon and may be subject to deletion.

Comment: It does add a check about admin.

Comment: /kill @e [type=EnderDragon] works.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command called `/kill` There are different targets you can select like `@a=all players,@s=self,@p=closest players to where the command was executed,@r=random player,@e=all entities` you also can direct it at a name or mob with `[type=(mob name)]`
However you claimed to want it to stay still so as for that there is two ways.

1. Follow the enderdragon to x and z coordinantes (0,0) where the enderdragon will fly in circles like the end stopping briefly on 0,0.

2.type in the chat `/give @s command_block` place the command block on creative mode and type in it `/tp @e[type=enderdragon] (x y z of dragon placement)` make the command block repeating and always active so all dragons will teleport to the x y z 20 times every second or every .05 seconds. If the dragon destroys blocks type the command in chat `/gamerule mobgriefing false`

> NOTE: creepers, ghasts, withers,(maybe silverfish), endermen and enderdragon will not break blocks after the last command unless you type `/gamerule mobgriefing false`

Answer (score 0):

try /kill @e [type=enderdragon] it worked for me <3

Answer (score -3):

`/kill @e ender_dragon`

This will kill everything in the world but it works for 1.10. I think that it only works on single player worlds but I'm not sure.

Comment: The syntax here is very wrong. `/kill` only takes one argument (a selector) while you've provided it with two, meaning the "ender_dragon" portion is completely ignored. This will kill every entity in the world and not just the dragon. Other answers have already provided the correct syntax. For 1.11, the entity ID is indeed "ender_dragon", but that's not what it is in 1.10.