# Removing the bugged Ender Dragon in Minecraft Realms version 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

On Minecraft Realms, in the End, I had summoned the Ender Dragon, twice. This was all in version 1.9. Of course, I did not know that the AI of the dragon was bugged, and now I want to remove the Ender Dragon.

I tried using the commands `/kill @e[type=EnderDragon,r=100]` and `/kill @e[type=EnderDragon]`, but alas, it did not work.

How do I remove the bugged Ender Dragon, in Minecraft Realms?

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: It didn't error out. Since the new update for the AI for the Ender Dragon was to big and they had to split his AI into multiple modes, for example the mode it starts off w/ is mode 0 or no AI whatsoever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a summoned Ender Dragon with no AI?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232788/how-do-i-remove-a-summoned-ender-dragon-with-no-ai)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try /kill @e[type=!Player]. This would,kill everything but the player. Or you can give yourself an enchanted sward and kill him by hand. But bow is better.

Comment: Bugged ender dragon cannot be hit, maybe :P

Comment: Forcelydated was right about hitting it, but the command:/kill @e[type=!Player] worked perfectly! Thanks!